# How can I calculate how much time a function takes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have jQuery functions; e.g A(), B() and C()
Each function makes some Ajax calls to different sites.

I want to calculate how much time it takes to run each function (I guess in milliseconds)
I just want to test my code in long loops and in different modern browsers (Safari/Chrome/IE10/Mozilla).
More specifically, I want to calculate how much time it takes to take a callback from each Ajax request (this is also the time that the function ends right?)
How might I achieve this?

Comment: No, the time a function ends is not the same time a callback fires, unless you're using synchronous AJAX calls.

Comment: many browsers have web developer tools that will monitor your AJAX requests and tell you how long they took.

Comment: So set a variable equal to the time of the Ajax call and then in the callback function compare that variable to the current time.

Comment: If you're measuring the response time of an ajax call, this is most likely dominated by network speed and server response time, not by the type of browser.  It's certainly not a function of javascript execution speed.  Show us the actual code of A(), B() and C() and you'll get much better advice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could get the time in milliseconds from the date object.

```
var start = new Date().getTime();

A();

function AJAXSuccessFunction() {
    console.log(new Date().getTime() - start);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
//set start point anywhere you want
var start = new Date(); 
//when done,
var end = new Date();

//to profile milliseconds, just do 
var duration = end - start;
```

Answer (score 3):

[Nowadays](http://caniuse.com/#search=performance.now), you can use [`perfomance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now). This function uses the `navigationStart` attribute as a start time;

> This attribute must return the time immediately after the user agent
>   finishes prompting to unload the previous document. If there is no
>   previous document, this attribute must return the same value as
>   fetchStart.

As for a real life code example:

```
// Store the start
var start = performance.now();

// Do some operation
for(var i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var j = i*i;
}

// Profile the milliseconds it took to do the job
var duration = (performance.now() - start);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now use , console.time('fn1') and console.timeEnd('fn1')

So if you are calling a function like doAwesomeStuff() and want to see how much time it takes to execute it just do,

```
console.time('fn1')
doAwesomeStuff()
console.timeEnd('fn1')
```

fn1 - can be anything.

Comment: This is what I recommend. This is the easiest way to do such timing. However, the performance API is also pretty sweet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but if you want to know how much time was spent processing a function, you can use Chrome's DevTools (or similar tools in other browsers) to check that.

Go to the page you want to examine, open DevTools, go to `Profiles` tab and select 'Collect Javascript CPU profile' and hit `Start` to start recording.

Refresh your page and when it has completed loading, `Stop` the recording. You'll get a list of functions executed and time that was spent processing it.

[image: Sample Screenshot of Profiles Tab in Dev Tools]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use more precisely [performance.now()](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/timing-javascript-code-high-resolution-timestamps)

```js
// Take a timestamp at the beginning.
var start = performance.now();

// Execute the code being timed.
console.log("your function is here")

// Take a final timestamp.
var end = performance.now();

// Calculate the time taken and output the result in the console
console.log('doTasks took ' + (end - start) + ' milliseconds to execute.');
```