# Determine execution time From beforeSend to Success in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, execution

Is possible to Determine execution time (seconds) in Jquery ajax request ? between beforeSend function to success or error function, like beforeSend -> 30 secnds ->success, may be you gusy have the answer, i tough it same like php  execution time function, but i have no clue how to that, i wanna make some progress bar process but from client side not from server side after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the time in milliseconds from the date object.

```
var beforeSend = new Date().getTime();

YourAjaxCallMethod();

function SuccessFunctionOfMyAjaxCall() {
    console.log(new Date().getTime() - start);
}
```

Borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7314183/1182982)

Comment: that great solution, i don't event think as simple as that, thanks dude, that what exactly i need

Answer (score 0):

Just use the setTimeout function in the success parameter:

```
beforeSend: function(){ 
       -animation (your progress bar)- 
       }
success: function(msg){
     setTimeout(function(){
               -show your success-  
           },3000);
         }
```